# plotly animation not working in shiny app?

Tags: shiny, plotly

I tried to use ploty in my shiny app but it turns out the same plotly works locally but failed to launch when deploy in shiny app, which shows only blank. 
This plotly code works locally,

```
   plot_ly(caseonly,
        x = ~  cases,
        y = ~ county,
        frame = ~ date,
        type = "scatter",
        mode = "markers"
    ) %>%
     layout(showlegend = TRUE) %>%
    animation_opts(frame = 100, redraw = FALSE)
```

However when I put the code chuck inside a shiny app it come back with blank page ? Any hints?

An sample shiny app.

```
    header <- dashboardHeader()
    sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(selectInput("County", "Please select:", c("King" = 0, "Queen" = 1)))

    body <- dashboardBody(box(width = 14, plotlyOutput(outputId = "DI")))

    # UI
    ui <- dashboardPage(
      skin = "blue",
      header=header,
      sidebar=sidebar,
      body = body
    )


    # SERVER
    server <- function(input, output) {
     output$DI <- renderPlotly({
     plot_ly(caseonly,
        x = ~  cases,
        y = ~ county,
        frame = ~ date,
        type = "scatter",
        mode = "markers"
     ) %>%
     layout(showlegend = TRUE) %>%
     animation_opts(frame = 100, redraw = FALSE)
      })
     }

     shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And here is the dataset I'm using:

````
        > dput(head(caseonly,n=60))
structure(list(fips = c(1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 
1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 
1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 
1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 
1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 
1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 
1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L, 1073L
), county = c("Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", 
"Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", 
"Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", 
"Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", 
"Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", 
"Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", 
"Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", 
"Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", 
"Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", 
"Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", 
"Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", 
"Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", 
"Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", 
"Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", 
"Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", "Jefferson County", 
"Jefferson County"), state = c("AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", 
"AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", 
"AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", 
"AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", 
"AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", 
"AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL"
), date = c("1/22/2020", "1/23/2020", "1/24/2020", "1/25/2020", 
"1/26/2020", "1/27/2020", "1/28/2020", "1/29/2020", "1/30/2020", 
"1/31/2020", "2/1/2020", "2/10/2020", "2/11/2020", "2/12/2020", 
"2/13/2020", "2/14/2020", "2/15/2020", "2/16/2020", "2/17/2020", 
"2/18/2020", "2/19/2020", "2/2/2020", "2/20/2020", "2/21/2020", 
"2/22/2020", "2/23/2020", "2/24/2020", "2/25/2020", "2/26/2020", 
"2/27/2020", "2/28/2020", "2/29/2020", "2/3/2020", "2/4/2020", 
"2/5/2020", "2/6/2020", "2/7/2020", "2/8/2020", "2/9/2020", "3/1/2020", 
"3/10/2020", "3/11/2020", "3/12/2020", "3/13/2020", "3/14/2020", 
"3/15/2020", "3/16/2020", "3/17/2020", "3/18/2020", "3/19/2020", 
"3/2/2020", "3/20/2020", "3/21/2020", "3/22/2020", "3/23/2020", 
"3/24/2020", "3/25/2020", "3/26/2020", "3/27/2020", "3/28/2020"
), cases = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
5L, 12L, 17L, 21L, 25L, 34L, 0L, 50L, 61L, 71L, 86L, 91L, 129L, 
169L, 179L, 214L), deaths = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), BedLicensed = c(4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 
4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 
4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 
4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 
4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 
4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 
4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 4473L, 
4473L, 4473L), TotPop = c(659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 
659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 
659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 
659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 
659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 
659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 
659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 
659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 
659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L, 659892L
), rate = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    deathrate = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 60L), class = "data.frame")```
````

Comment: Using your code and the ````mtcars```` dataset, I am able to create the plotly output in the dashboard. Can you share your data by pasting the output of ````dput(caseonly)```` into your question? If the data is too long you can use ````dput(head(caseonly, 10))````. Copy the output in the console and paste it into your question.

Comment: Did you open the app in RStudio or in the browser ? There are issues of this type in the RStudio browser.

Comment: Thanks for you reply! I added the sample data. I tried both Rstudio and in browser, neither works.